# How do I search files without certain extensions in their names?

Tags: files, find, locate

I would like to search recursively in all the files and directories under a directory for some strings e.g. `library`.

I also would like to exclude files and directories which store downloaded webpages but  are not `.html` or `.htm` files (which are still of my interest), such as:

- files whose filenames have certain extensions, such as `.js`, `.css`, `.png`, `.gif`,`.jpeg`, and
- directories whose names are ended with `_files`.

so how shall I do that? I am thinking about using `locate` before `find`, because `locate` is faster, but I don't know `locate` can do it or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might do what you want:

```
find . -name '*_files' -type d -prune -o ! \( -name '*.js' -o -name '*.css' -o -name '*.png' -o -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.jpeg' \)
```

If that prints out a reasonable list then add `-print0 | xargs -o grep -i library` to do the actual searching.

Comment: Thanks! Will your way be faster than first locate for `library`, and then do some text processing (?) on its output to eliminate those unwanted files and dirs?

Comment: locate searches for file *names* not contents. So you can't `locate library` and have that do anything even close to what you want. That being said, if you *could* use locate as a first pass for this operation that might be faster than just using `find` directly but that is going to depend on the volume of files `find` has to search and other factors.

Comment: doesn't `find` also search among file names not contents?

Comment: @Tim Yes, which is why the output is sent to grep to search for library in the contents. You could use locate for the file name matching (but only in the positive direction I believe).

Comment: What do you mean by "in the positive direction"?

Comment: I mean I don't believe that locate can be told to search for files that *don't* match a pattern. So you couldn't do the "doesn't match one of these extensions" matching you were asking for and that the find command I wrote does.

Comment: I see. If first `locate` for `library`, how do you process its output to eliminate those files and dirs with those special strings in their names?

Comment: `locate library` will locate files with "library" in their names, which, unless I wildly misunderstood the question, was not what you wanted. If you could use `locate` as a first pass you would need to use grep/awk/sed/etc. to eliminate the files with names you didn't want and then pipe that to `xargs` to search them with `grep`.